# how can I analyze dart code to remove duplicate classes?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-analyzer

this question is about static analysis of dart code.
**How can I analyze the dart code or visit the each class within a dart file so I could remove the duplicate class**, I know these tools exists but i don't know how exactly implement it
PS:duplicate class exists due to code generation using quicktype.

```
//psuedo code
classes = readTheDartFileSomeHow();
var map = Map<string,string>()
for (final myClass in classes){
 map.putIfAbsent(myClass.name,myClass);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try develop custom plugin to Dart Analyzer and add it to your project. Start with [Official Tutorial](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/pkg/analyzer_plugin/doc/tutorial/tutorial.md) for get a short overview about how it works.

Also, community has some custom plugins and you can explore source code for find useful practises (for example: [dart-code-metrics)](https://github.com/wrike/dart-code-metrics) and [dart-enum-to-string-check](https://github.com/fartem/dart-enum-to-string-check)).

Comment: yeah, but how do i enumerate through dart classes present in a dart file?

Comment: You can try to detect class declaration and try to retrieve a file that contains this class.